# WishList boolean toggle button toggles all items in ng-repeat instead of single item

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Within a `ng-repeat="item in items"` I have a Wishlist boolean button which can be `true` or `false`.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-controller="ItemCtrl as ctrl">
  <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="ctrl.toggleWish(item)">
    <i class="material-icons">{{ctrl.hasWished(item) ? 'favorite' : 'favorite_border' }}</i>
  </md-button>
</div>
```

with the `hasWished(item)` function, I check if the currently logged in User id (`Auth._currentUser.id`) is within the user ids stored within the wishlist of the item.

The JSON output of a single `item` looks simplified like this:

```
{"id":1,"title":"This is a tile","wishes":2,"wishlists":[{"user_id":2},{"user_id":3}]}
```

So the `hasWished(item)` function should return `true` or `false`:

```
  this.hasWished = function(item) {
    return item.wishlists.some(function(wishlist) {
      return wishlist.user_id === Auth._currentUser.id  // returns true if currently logged in user id is on wishlist
    });
  };
```

That is working so far. With the `toggleWish` function I want to toggle the `hasWished(item)` from true to false, or vice versa:

```
  this.toggleWish = function(item) {
    if (!this.hasWished(item)) {
      this.hasWished = function(item){return true};
      items.wish(item); // sends PUT request to API
      item.wishes += 1;
      ToastService.show(item.title + ' added to Wish List');
    } else {
      this.hasWished = function(item){return false};
      items.unWish(item); // sends DELETE request to API
      item.wishes -= 1;
      ToastService.show(item.product + ' removed from Wish List');
    }
  };
```

Currently toggleWish does toggle, but toggles all `items` within `ng-repeat="item in items"` to true or false (depending if they were true or false before). instead of only the single item, where the `toggleWish(item)` button was clicked.

I need to somehow set `hasWished` for each single item to true or false - independent of the other items, while still checking if the user has wished this item previously (with the current `hasWished` function).

I am stuck here and I appreciate your advise!

Comment: `this.hasWished = function(item){return true};` returns true for every item

Comment: yes, do you know how to change this, so that it only returns true to the selected item?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After you fetch your JSON, compute flags that your template can use.

Then toggle those flags.

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-controller="ItemCtrl as ctrl">
  <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="ctrl.toggleWishFlag($index)">
    <i class="material-icons">
        {{ctrl.flags.wish[$index] ? 'favorite' : 'favorite_border' }}
    </i>
  </md-button>
</div>
```

Compute your flags:

```
var self = this;
this.computeFlags = function(items) {
    self.flags = self.flags || {};
    self.flags.wish = [];
    for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
         self.flags.wish.push(
             self.hasWished(items[i]);
         );
    };
};
```

Toggle your flags:

```
this.toggleWishFlag = function(index) {
    var item = items(index);
    if (!self.flags.wish[index]) {
      self.flags.wish[index] = true;
      // send PUT request to API
      ToastService.show(item.title + ' added to Wish List');
    } else {
      self.flags.wish[index] = false;
      // send DELETE request to API
      ToastService.show(item.product + ' removed from Wish List');
    }
  };
```

Notice my use of the `$index` special property in the HTML. For more information on that see the [AngularJS ngRepeat API Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

Answer (score 0):

```
this.hasWished = function(item){return true};
```

is a function in the controller, so it is not something specific for an item.
You should store a flag in the item. Something like

```
 this.toggleWish = function(item) {
    if (!this.hasWished(item)) {
      items.wish(item); // sends PUT request to API
      item.hasWished = true;
      item.wishes += 1;
      ToastService.show(item.title + ' added to Wish List');
    } else {
      items.unWish(item); // sends DELETE request to API
      itme.hasWished false;
      item.wishes -= 1;
      ToastService.show(item.product + ' removed from Wish List');
    }
  };
```

and then in the html use that flag to show or not

```
{{item.hasWished ? 'favorite' : 'favorite_border' }}
```

Comment: the only problem with this is, that when the page is reloaded, it won't check in the database if hasWished = true or false

Comment: you need to set the value the first time when you load the data manually.